# Returning an array in R

Tags: r

Is it possible to return an array of values in R from a function call? I have a method which should store values from a computation in an array and returns it to the caller but in reality all it does is return the first element of the array. The function is given below.

```
binsmooth_trials = function(x, y){
  bin_lens = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)
  bin_len_errs = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  for (i in 1:bin_lens){
    rss_error = binsmooth(x, y, i)
    bin_len_errs[i] = rss_error
  }
  return bin_len_errs
}
```

Comment: it should be `1:length(bin_lens)`? Also, you should declare `bin_len_errs <- rep(0, length(bin_lens))` before the loop so that your vector is not growing inside the loop (which will result in copying the object every time thus making it run slow).

Comment: You also want `return(bin_len_errs)` not `return bin_len_errs`

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want here is:

```
binsmooth_trials <- function(x, y) {
  bin_lens = seq(from=10, to=100, by=10)
  bin_len_errs = vector("numeric", length=length(bin_lens))
  for(i in bin_lens){
    bin_len_errs[i] = binsmooth(x, y, i)
    }
  bin_len_errs
}
```